# Reading numpy arrays from disk in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am a tensorflow beginner, trying to read numpy arrays stored on disk into TF using the TextLineReader. But when I read the arrays in TF, I see values different from the original array. Could someone please point to the mistake I am making here? Please see a sample code below. Thanks

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import csv

#Write two numpy arrays to disk 
a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
np.save("a.npy",a,allow_pickle=False)

b = np.arange(30).reshape(5, 6)
np.save("b.npy",b,allow_pickle=False)

with open('files.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    filewriter.writerow(['a.npy', 'b.npy'])


# Load a csv with the two array filenames

csv_filename = "files.csv"
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([csv_filename])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
_, csv_filename_tf = reader.read(filename_queue)


record_defaults = [tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string), tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string)]
filename_i,filename_j = tf.decode_csv(
    csv_filename_tf, record_defaults=record_defaults)

file_contents_i = tf.read_file(filename_i)
file_contents_j = tf.read_file(filename_j)

bytes_i = tf.decode_raw(file_contents_i, tf.int16)
array_i = tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.slice(bytes_i, [0], [3*5]), tf.int16), [3, 5])

bytes_j = tf.decode_raw(file_contents_j, tf.int16)
array_j = tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.slice(bytes_j, [0], [5*6]), tf.int16), [5, 6])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    a_out, b_out = (sess.run([array_i, array_j]))

    print(a)
    print(a_out)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Here is the output that I get:

Expected output (a)

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]]
```

Received output: (a_out)

```
[[20115 19797 22864     1   118]
 [10107 25956 25459 10098  8250]
 [15399 14441 11303 10016 28518]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the tensorflow decode_raw and numpy's np.save are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy's zip files `.npz`

To save variables `a` `b`:

```
weights = {w.name : sess.run(w) for w in [a, b]}
np.savez(path, **weights)
```

To load:

```
weights = [a, b]
npz_weights = np.load(path)
for i,k in enumerate([w.name for w in weights]):
    sess.run(weights[i].assign(npz_weights[k]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to figure out what was happening I printed `bytes_i` instead of `array_i`.

```
a_out, b_out = (sess.run([bytes_i, bytes_j]))
print(a_out)
```

And I obtained the following list:

```
[20115 19797 22864     1   118 10107 25956 25459 10098  8250 15399 14441
 11303 10016 28518 29810 24946 24430 29295 25956 10098  8250 24902 29548
 11365 10016 26739 28769 10085  8250 13096  8236 10549  8236  8317  8224
  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224
  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224  8224
  8224  8224  8224  2592     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     2     0     0     0     3     0     0     0     4     0     0     0
     5     0     0     0     6     0     0     0     7     0     0     0
     8     0     0     0     9     0     0     0    10     0     0     0
    11     0     0     0    12     0     0     0    13     0     0     0
    14     0     0     0]
```

It appears that there is a header in front of the data stored in the numpy file. Moreover it seems that data values are saved as `int64` and not as `int16`.

## Solution

First specify the type of the values in the array:

```
a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5).astype(np.int16)
b = np.arange(30).reshape(5, 6).astype(np.int16)
```

Then read the last bytes of the file:

```
array_i = tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.slice(bytes_i,
                                      begin=[tf.size(bytes_i) - (3*5)],
                                      size=[3*5]), tf.int16), [3, 5])
array_j = tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.slice(bytes_j,
                                      begin=[tf.size(bytes_j) - (5*6)],
                                      size=[5*6]), tf.int16), [5, 6])
```